# Is it possible to table() two columns in a way that display the sum horizontally and vertically?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr

I have

```
> table(y$treatment,y$WHO)

           1  2  3  4
  SSTR    43 34 20 27
  SSA     23 28 25  0
  Control  0  0  0  0
```

I am looking for a way to display the sum of each row and column generated by `table()`. Thus, the expected output is:

```
           1  2  3  4
  SSTR    43 34 20 27 124
  SSA     23 28 25  0 76
  Control  0  0  0  0 0
          66 62 45 27
```

I am particularly interested in `dplyr`-solutions.

My data

```
y <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("SSTR", "SSA", "Control"), class = "factor"), 
    WHO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), na.action = structure(c(`152` = 152L, 
`193` = 193L), class = "omit"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 
119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do `colSums()` and `rowSums()` not do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to consider:

```
x<-table(y$treatment,y$WHO)


rowcoltotals <- addmargins(x, FUN = list(Total = sum), quiet = TRUE)
```

output:

```
            1   2   3   4 Total
  SSTR     43  34  20  27   124
  SSA      23  28  25   0    76
  Control   0   0   0   0     0
  Total    66  62  45  27   200
```